# Anyone has any idea how to start on Opentelemetry browser instrumentation for a vue.js application?

Tags: vue.js, open-telemetry

```js
import { WebTracerProvider, BatchSpanProcessor, ConsoleSpanExporter, SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web';
import { ZoneContextManager } from '@opentelemetry/context-zone';
import { Resource }  from '@opentelemetry/resources';
import { SemanticResourceAttributes } from '@opentelemetry/semantic-conventions';
import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
import { getWebAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-web';

const provider = new WebTracerProvider({
    resource: new Resource({
      [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: 'browser',
    }),
  });

providerWithZone.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
provider.register({
    contextManager: new ZoneContextManager()
  });

registerInstrumentations({
    instrumentations: [
      getWebAutoInstrumentations(),
    ],
  });
```

Any guidance on browser instrumentation for a vue.js application. I am very new to Vue and as well as Opentelemtry. Tried following their github codebase also but not much of a progress there also.

Tried https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/browser/ but no progress. I am not sure exactly how to approach.

ConsoleSpanExporter is supposed to provide trace objects in browser console right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have manage to implement Otel in Vuejs 3 app. I am using ZipkinExporter to collect the data, but any provider that support oltp can be used in the mixin you will need to replace ZipkinExporter with the OTLPTraceExporter and have it configured there(url, API-Key).
Now I am going to present in a detailed manner my implementation:

1. I have installed the following packages:

```
npm install @opentelemetry/api \
@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-web \
@opentelemetry/context-zone \
@opentelemetry/exporter-zipkin \ 
@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web \
```

2. In my vue app I created a directory called opentelemetry and there I placed a file called otelprovider.js with the following content:

```
import { SimpleSpanProcessor, WebTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web';
import { ZoneContextManager } from '@opentelemetry/context-zone';
import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
import { getWebAutoInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/auto-instrumentations-web';
import { ZipkinExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-zipkin';
import { Resource } from '@opentelemetry/resources';

const provider = new WebTracerProvider({
  resource: Resource.default().merge(new Resource({
    // Replace with any string to identify this service in your system
    'service.name': 'HOW_IS_CALLED_YOUR_FRONTEND_APP',
  })),
});
const exporter = new ZipkinExporter();
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));

provider.register({
  contextManager: new ZoneContextManager(),

});

// Registering instrumentations
registerInstrumentations({
  instrumentations: [
    getWebAutoInstrumentations(),
  ],
});
```

3. In my App.vue in the script setup part I import directly the file I have created before. My app.vue file looks like this(I shorten it since there are a lot of stuff there)

```
<script setup>
.....
import 'opentelemetry/otelprovider';
......

</script>

<template>
  <RouterViewWrapper />
</template>
```

Basically I point out directly to file I have created that is in directory opentelemetry and is called otelprovider. Once you start the application you can see the telemetry in ZipkinExporter or if you prefer you can easily replace it with ConsoleExporter. Please note that what I present here is a poc and some improvements can be done mostly use batch instead of span processor.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Did something similar, Now facing build issues. Terser
Unexpected token punc «:», expected punc «,»

Answer (score 0):

There is no Vue specific instrumentation in OTel (at least not in the official Github repos). However, the existing web instrumentation (document load, XHR/fetch) will work with any frameworks.

In your example, I see that you are creating a WebTracerProvider in instance variable `provider`, but then you are adding a span processor to `providerWithZone`; these should be the same. Aside from that, your example should work. Please provide more details if you are still having issues (error message etc.).

Comment: We are waiting for you to send us data. Please follow the instructions below to send events from your application - I am seeing this from honeycomb. And I don't see traces in console. May be I am initializing Otel it a wrong place in vue